# How to print the name of a variable with parameters?

Tags: c++, c

I would like to print : `table_name[variable_value]`

by giving ONE input : `table_name[variable_name]`

Let me explain a simpler case with a toy solution based on a macro:

```
int i = 1771;
```

I can print the `variable_name` with

`#define toy_solution(x) cout << #x ;`

If I execute

`toy_solution(i);`

"i" will be printed.

Now, imagine there is a well-allocated table `T`.

I would like to write in the program:

```
solution(T[i]);
```

and to read on the screen `"T[1771]"`.

An ideal solution would treat the two cases, that is :

`ideal_solution(i)` would print `i`.

`ideal_solution(T[i])` would print `T[1771]`.

It is not important to me to use a macro or a function.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: though Mr anonymous is right, a little explaination is needed: the preprocessor left hand side part need to be compatible with C/C++ syntax/grammar, and thus you can't invent things like `toy_solution(T[i]) -> cout << #T << "[" << "i" << "]"`. But if you do that, then it'd even be better to use @lizusek's solution because his solution is 100% valid and clean C++ that the compiler can optimize easily, when you can avoid using macros for real code, choose real code.

Comment: I edited my initial message to precise that I would desire a solution with only ONE input. In other words, solution(T[i]) would print "T[1771]" and solution(i) would print "i".

Comment: @user3387689 can you please explain us what the title means? please consider reword it in accordance to the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I might regret asking - but why do you want to do this?

Comment: I would like to have a more readable code, to gain time, to have a language closer to human language and to improve my C++ knowledge and all this, without contradict kiss philosophy.

Answer (score 5):

```
#define toy_solution(x, i) cout << #x << "[" << i << "]"
```

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to print : `table_name[variable_value]`
>
> by giving ONE input : `table_name[variable_name]`

well, as you did not understand my comment, I'll say out loud in an answer:

## what you want to do is not possible

### You *have* to choose between either @Alin's solution or @lizusek.

I think that @lizusek's solution is better because you're writing C++ code, so if you can do something that gives the same result than with using macros, you should use plain C++ code.

*edit: let my try to explain why this is not possible*

so what you want is:

```
f(T[i]) -> T, i
```

The only way you could write that so it would make sense in preprocessor is:

```
#define f(T[i]) cout<<#T#<<#i#
```

but then the preprocessor will give an error, because you can't index an array as a function (even a macro function) parameter:

```
test.c:5:12: error: expected comma in macro parameter list
#define f(T[i]) cout<<#T#<<#i#
           ^
```

If you try to do the same thing using a C++ function, then it's even more non-sense, as a function call such as:

```
toy_solution(t[i]);
```

would actually be translated to the value `t[i]` points to at runtime, so inside the function you'll never be able to known that the given value was actually in an array. So what you want is wrong, and you should stick to good coding practices: using a function and if what you want is:

```
toy_solution(t[i]);
```

then use:

```
toy_solution("t", i);
```

### Possible solutions ***that you should never use***

well, when I say it's not possible, it's that the only solutions I can think off are so twisted that you'd be insane to actually use them in your code… And if you do, I hope I'll never read one of your code or I may become violent :-) That's why I won't show you how or give you any code that could help do what I'm about to tell you.

- use a template system

You could either write your code using your own template system or use one commonly used for HTML processing to process your source code through it and apply a transformation rule such as:

```
toy_solution(t[i]) -> toy_solution("t", t[i])
```

it's definitely possible, but it makes your build chain even more complicated and dependant on more tools. C/C++ build toolchain are complicated enough, please don't make it worst.

Or you code make your own fork of C and of a C compiler to change the syntax rules so what you want becomes possible. Though, I personnally would never use your fork, and then I'd go trolling and flaming about this on HN, deeply regretting to have given you such a bad idea :-)

- use a custom class to encapsulate your arrays in

if you do something like:

```
template<T>
class Element {
    T value;
    List<T> _owner;
    […]
}
template<T>
class List {
    Element<T> values[];
    std::string _name;
    […]
}
```

so that when you call the function

```
toy_solution(T[i]);
```

the implementation would look like:

```
void toy_solution(Element<T> e) {
    std::cout<<e.get_list_name()<<" "<<e.get_value()<<std::endl;
}
```

but that's sooo much boilerplate and overhead just to avoid doing a simple function definition that does not look as nice as you dream of, that I find it really *stupid* to do so.

Comment: "Not possible" seems strange to me in this situation. If I reformulate the question, what I'd like is to analyze a given input in the following way. 1) Do not interpret what is outside the brackets. 2) Interpret what is inside the brackets. (ex 1 Input `T[i]`. Output `T[1771]`, ex 2 Input `i`. Output `i`).

Comment: the way you're putting it in your comment is definitely **NOT POSSIBLE**. I'm giving you the only way you may achieve that, so you can understand how much work that would mean to do what you want, just because you do not want to stick with good C and C++ practice. C and C++ are strict (read statically and strongly typed) languages with a strict syntax. C++ is a bit more flexible, giving you the second solution, but it's still a terrible idea you **do not want to implement**. I really hope you're getting my point, which is *Keep it Simple, Stupid* and use simple, standard code like suggested.

Comment: I really appreciate your last answer. This time, you convince me that there is no obvious clean solution. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function as simple as that:

```
void solution( std::string const& t, int i) {
  std::cout << t << "[" << i << "]";
}
```

usage:

```
int i = 1771;
solution( "T", i);
```

You can also write a macro, but be aware that this is not type safe. Function should be preferred.